# C# Unity помощь

Tags: c#, unity3d

Неправильно работает скрипт в игре (2D)
Скрипт  такой:
Проверяем позицию, и если она не равна 0, то двигаем объект, пока не будет 0, в нужную сторону.
Всё работает хорошо, но скрипт проверяет только одну сторону - Bottom. А сторону Top продолжает тянуть. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

```
public float speed = 5f, checkPos = 0f;
private RectTransform rec;

void Start()
{
    rec = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}
void Update()
{
    if (rec.offsetMin.y != checkPos)
        rec.offsetMin += new Vector2 (rec.offsetMin.x, speed);
        rec.offsetMax += new Vector2 (rec.offsetMax.x, speed);
}
```

[image: так должно быть]

[image: Так выходит]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Старый ответ я удалил, потому что он был не по теме.
Не понимал в чем у вас ошибка, пока не вставил ваш код в VisualStudio, который убрал табуляцию во второй строке после if. Обе строки условия у вас должны срабатывать только при условии, поэтому добавьте фигурные скобки.

```
if (rec.offsetMin.y != checkPos) {
    rec.offsetMin += new Vector2 (rec.offsetMin.x, speed);
    rec.offsetMax += new Vector2 (rec.offsetMax.x, speed);
}
```

Также очень важное замечание! Если у вас сдвиг (offset) будет не кратен скорости, то ваши кнопки отправятся в бесконечное путешествие в просторы вселенной над экраном, так как сдвиг будет (допустим, изначально -9.999):

- -9.999
- -4.999
- 1.999
- 6.999

То есть сдвиг никогда не будет равен 0. Таким образом, если произойдет малейший сдвиг на буквально погрешность, ваши кнопки не остановятся. Тоже произойдет, если вы сделаете скорость, например, не 5, а 6, а сдвиг кнопок будет КРАТЕН 5, но не КРАТЕН 6. Поэтому советую вам вместо !=0 написать <0

Answer (score 2):

Такие временные действия описываются не в `Update`, а с помощью корутин.

```
// я бы ещё прикрутил кривую для плавности (но не обязательно)
// настраивается в инспекторе
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _curve;
private RectTransform _rect;

private void Start () {
    _rect  = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    StartCoroutine(OffsetCoroutine(_rect, 1f, Vector2.zero, Vector2.zero, _curve));
}

private IEnumerator OffsetCoroutine (RectTransform rect, float time, Vector2 targetMin, Vector2 targetMax, AnimationCurve curve = null) {
    float Timer = 0;
    Vector2 BaseMin = rect.offsetMin;
    Vector2 BaseMax = rect.offsetMax;
    while (Timer < time) {
        float Way = Timer/time;
        if (curve != null) {
            rect.offsetMin = BaseMin+(targetMin-BaseMin)*curve.Evaluate(Way);
            rect.offsetMax = BaseMax+(targetMax-BaseMax)*curve.Evaluate(Way);
        } else {
            rect.offsetMin = BaseMin+(targetMin-BaseMin)*Way;
            rect.offsetMax = BaseMax+(targetMax-BaseMax)*Way;
        }
        yield return null;
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    rect.offsetMin = targetMin;
    rect.offsetMax = targetMax;
}
```